# I can`t load scripts components in angular.js

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I'm having some problems with my code. I made some components on my site, and when I place the script it only appears the last one. I already tried placing the files in different folders, but the problem remains. 
All the components and the main module are in the app folder.
Thanks for your help guys!

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <title>TEMPLATED</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/main.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Header -->
    <header-component></header-component>

    <!-- Banner -->
    <banner-component></banner-component>

    <!-- One -->
    <one-component></one-component>


    <!-- Scripts -->
        <script src="public/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="public/js/skel.min.js"></script>
        <script src="public/js/util.js"></script>
        <script src="public/js/main.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="app/app.module.js"></script>
        <script src="app/banner/banner.component.js"></script>
        <script src="app/header/header.component.js"></script>
        <script src="app/one/one.component.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

app.module.js

```
(function(){
    'use strict';
        angular
            .module('app', []);
 }());
```

header.component.js

```
(function(){
    'use strict';
        angular
            .module('app', [])
            .component('headerComponent', {
                bindings: {},
                templateUrl : 'app/header/header.html',
                controller : headerCtrl
            })

            function headerCtrl($scope){
                console.log('header')
                $scope.logo = "theory";
                $scope.home = "Home";
                $scope.generic = 'Generic'
                $scope.elements = "Elements";

            }
 }());
```

banner.component.js

```
(function(){
    'use strict';
        angular
            .module('app', [])
            .component('bannerComponent', {
                bindings: {},
                templateUrl : 'app/banner/banner.html',
                controller : bannerCtrl
            })

            function bannerCtrl($scope){
                console.log('banner');
                $scope.welcome = "Welcooome to Theory";


            }
 }());
```

one.component.js

```
(function(){
    'use strict';
        angular
            .module('app', [])
            .component('oneComponent', {
                bindings: {},
                templateUrl : 'app/one/one.html',
                controller : oneCtrl
            })

            function oneCtrl($scope){
                $scope.articulos = [
                    {
                        titulos : "Magna tempus sed amet 1",
                        textos : "Morbi interdum mollis sapien. Sed ac risus. Phasellus lacinia, magna a ullamcorper laoreet, lectus arcu.",
                        btn : "More"
                    },
                    {
                        titulos : "Magna tempus sed amet 2",
                        textos : "Morbi interdum mollis sapien. Sed ac risus. Phasellus lacinia, magna a ullamcorper laoreet, lectus arcu.",
                        btn : "More"                        
                    },
                    {
                        titulos : "Magna tempus sed amet 3",
                        textos : "Morbi interdum mollis sapien. Sed ac risus. Phasellus lacinia, magna a ullamcorper laoreet, lectus arcu.",
                        btn : "More"                        
                    },


                ]


            }
 }());
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D56iw.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're bootstrapping a separate app in each of your files here.

Instead, bootstrap just one, and then register all the components and controllers to the one.

```
// bootstrap just one app
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

// then register all your controllers to the same app
app.controller('oneCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  // your controller code
}]);

// and register all your components to the same app
app.component('oneComponent', {
  bindings: {},
  templateUrl : 'app/one/one.html',
  controller : 'oneCtrl'
});
```

You're only seeing the `<one-component></one-component>` component because it's the last one you load, effectively overriding the previous app declarations.

Comment: I've already tried. Inject the modules of the other components into one.module.js and in the console says : Module 'appone' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Comment: @Pil: I've updated my answer with a commented code example, and improved word choice.